# How to Map a Drive using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I map a network drive using C#. I don't want to use `net use` or any third party API.

Heard about UNC paths in C# code but not quite sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`WnetAddConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413(VS.85).aspx) functions available in the native `mpr.dll`.

You will have to write the P/Invoke signatures and structures to call through to the unmanaged function. You can find resources on P/Invoke on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net).

This is [the signature for `WNetAddConnection2` on pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr.WNetAddConnection2):

```
[DllImport("mpr.dll")]    
public static extern int WNetAddConnection2(
   ref NETRESOURCE netResource,
   string password, 
   string username, 
   int flags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ the [NetShareAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525384%28VS.85%29.aspx) Windows' API.  You'll need to use PInvoke to get your hands on it, of course.

Comment: `NetShareAdd` creates a share. The question is about how to map an existing share.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard feature in .net to map networkdrives but you can find a good wrapper here if you dont want to execute the Native calls by yourself: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/windowsservices/article.php/c12357

Comment: Link is dead.  Gives a 404 on codeguru.

Answer (score 0):

More straight-forward solution is to use `Process.Start()`

```
internal static int RunProcess(string fileName, string args, string workingDir)
{
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        Arguments = args,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = workingDir
    };

    using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        if (process == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to start {startInfo.FileName}");
        }

        process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => e.Data.Log();
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data)) { new Exception(e.Data).Log(); }
            };

        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();

        return process.ExitCode;
    }
}
```

Once you have the above, use below create/delete mapped drive as necessary.

```
Converter.RunProcess("net.exe", @"use Q: \\server\share", null);

Converter.RunProcess("net.exe", "use Q: /delete", null);
```

Comment: Simpler version - make sure you're "using System.Diagnostics;" for System.Diagnostics.Process:
 `char DriveLetter = 'R';`
 `string Path = @"\\contoso\share\things";`
 `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\net.exe", "use " + DriveLetter + ": " + Path));`

Comment: This defeats the entire purpose of programming instead of scripting.